# Use repeat of format for many variables on the same line

Tags: ruby, format, output

```
puts "%-30s%2s%3d%2s%3d%2s%3d%2s%3d%2s%3d" % [tn,ln,a,ln,b,ln,c,ln,d,ln,e]
```

This is Ruby, but many languages use this formatting. I have forgotten how to output several variables in the same format, without repeating the format in each case. Here, I want "%3d%2s" for 5 integers, each separated by a '|'

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and outputs, so that your question contains a complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the following.

```
def print_my_string(tn, ln, *ints)
  fmt = "%-10s" + ("|#{"%2s" % ln}%3d" * ints.size) + "|"
  puts fmt % [tn, *ints]
end
```

Then, for example,

```
print_my_string("hello", "ho", 2, 77, 453, 61, 999)
```

displays

```
hello     |ho  2|ho 77|ho453|ho 61|ho999|
```

after having computed

```
fmt = "%-10s" + ("|#{"%2s" % ln}%3d" * ints.size) + "|"
  #=> %-10s|ho%3d|ho%3d|ho%3d|ho%3d|ho%3d|"
```